# Add more files to File Upload input type file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add more files to existing input type file.

If I add one file first and then want to add two more.

I am unable to get access to already added file.

I using Jquery change function. Alert in below code giving uploading value, but I want to get previously uploaded files and their values.

How can I do this?

```js
 $('#MyFileUpload').change(function (e) {             
     alert($("#MyFileUpload").val());             
     $('#MyFileUpload').prop("files", e.target.files);
});
```

Comment: Please clarify what steps or code you have used to try and accomplish this. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example You might consider a separate storage array. So if the user selects one file initially but maybe changes their mind and wants to add another file or change the files, they can manipulate the array of files. When ready to upload, you can use new Form Data to send all the resulting files.

Comment: @freedomn-m We don't know how many times user adds the files

Comment: @freedomn-m Can you show me how to add as needed? Also, How can I access these multiple files in asp.cs file(if you know of .Net)